# grunt-frontend cannot assign to read only property 'spidermonkey'

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I have a problem with [`grunt-frontend`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-frontend) package.

When I run `grunt` task I get:

```
Running "frontend-js:main" (frontend-js) task
Processing /assets/js/main.min.js
Warning: Cannot assign to read only property 'spidermonkey' of /assets/js/main.min.js Used --force, continuing.
```

What is going wrong?

I have `Gruntfile.js` configured like in the documentation:

```
'frontend-js': {
    main: {
        options: {
            minify: true,
            uglify: {}
        },

        files: {
            'out/js/f.js': [
                'test/js/file1.js',
                'test/js/file2.js'
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

When I set `minify: false` everything works normally, except minification of course.

Comment: grunt config? especially the 'frontend-js' block

Comment: @hereandnow78, updated.

Comment: sorry can't help there, but your config doesn't seem to match your error! `/assets/js/main.min.js` != `out/js/f.js`

Comment: I gust gave an example `Gruntfile`. Mine has just different paths.